# Change the displayed number of products in Woocommerce with Select dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to add a drop-down on products listing to change the displayed number of products. I am working on the latest version of Wordpress (4.8.2) and Woocommerce (3.1.2).

This is my code on `functions.php`

```
//save and load the chosen option from session
function jc_get_products_per_page(){

    global $woocommerce;

    $default = 5;
    $count = $default;
    $options = jc_get_products_per_page_options();

    // capture form data and store in session
    if(isset($_POST['jc-woocommerce-products-per-page'])){ 
        // set products per page from dropdown
        $products_max = intval($_POST['jc-woocommerce-products-per-page']);
        if($products_max != 0 && $products_max >= -1){
            $woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page = $products_max;
            return $products_max;
        }
    }
    // load product limit from session
    if(isset($woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page)){
        // set products per page from woo session
        $products_max = intval($woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page);
        if($products_max != 0 && $products_max >= -1){
            return $products_max;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
add_filter('loop_shop_per_page','jc_get_products_per_page');

//set the options for the dropdown
function jc_get_products_per_page_options(){
    $options = apply_filters( 'jc_products_per_page', array(
        5 => __('5', 'woocommerce'),
        10 => __('10', 'woocommerce'),
        15 => __('15', 'woocommerce'),
        20 => __('20', 'woocommerce')
    ));

    return $options;
}
//display the dropdown on front-end
function jc_woocommerce_products_per_page(){

    $options = jc_get_products_per_page_options();

    $current_value = jc_get_products_per_page();
    ?>
    <div class="products-per-page">
        <span>View:</span>
        <form action="" method="POST" class="woocommerce-products-per-page">
            <select name="jc-woocommerce-products-per-page" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <?php foreach($options as $value => $name): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php selected($value, $current_value); ?>><?php echo $name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'jc_woocommerce_products_per_page', 1);
```

So the problem is that when I change the dropdown, the page reload but the number of displayed products stay the same. The default. Any idea what is going wrong?

Edit: I tried to add a `return 2;` on the first row of the function and still doesn't work. So, it seems the `add_filter` doesn't work

Comment: have you ever tested this function `jc_get_products_per_page` (the one in your question) thoroughly to get it's output???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grabbed your code as is from your initial post and dropped it into a theme I'm developing for WooCommerce and it worked like a charm.

Obviously, that's not your case. But this leads me to believe that something else is likely also hooking into the `loop_shop_per_page` filter after your code is being called.

Before refactoring all of your code try setting the priority on your `add_filter` to something high, like so:

`add_filter('loop_shop_per_page','jc_get_products_per_page', 99);`

That should help to determine if it is an issue with your filter being overwritten by the same filter being called in another plugin or elsewhere in your theme.

Comment: It was that. There was a Woocommerce plugin that overrides my filter. Increasing the priority fixed it. So newbie mistake. Thanks

Comment: Since that code was copy-pasted into a theme you are developing and work like a charm (personally i think it is not so well written) can you explain this simple logic part.... when someone writes a paginator plugin and on the front end will have created a select box having values of nX5 where n=1,2,3... why on earth should on server side compare with something like this `if($products_max != 0 && $products_max >= -1){` when the input i expect is like this 5,10,15,20 ??? Can you please explain me? I am not a wordpress expert but those functions i really don't think that will work like a charm.

Comment: Not having written the original code myself I can't say for sure what the original developer was going for with that conditional check. It seems to be an extra assurance that what's being returned is an integer > 0. Particularly because it looks like someone could overwrite the select options with the `jc_products_per_page` filter. But I'll leave it to the original developer to explain their reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've changed my answer completely and tested the solution, so it should work, only thing is that the pagination was fully working, but it would be good if someone could improve on my answer.

Looking at woocommerce Docs however you should be filtering the `$cols` variable for it to work.  Apologises I couldn't tell exactly what you where doing with your code above so I've rewritten the scripts from scratch - but I think if you just used the `$cols` then you'd of probably of got there yourself.

Here's the new code:

```
    add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 20 );
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'new_loop_shop_per_page', 1);
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'mywoocommerce_products_per_page', 1, 50 );



    function new_loop_shop_per_page( $cols ) {

        session_start();
        $default = "5";
        $cols = $default;
        $submittedValue = "";
       // global $submittedvalue;
        $value0 = "5";
        $value1 = "10";
        $value2 = "15";
        $value3 = "20";

        if (isset($_POST["ProductsPerPage"])) {

         $_SESSION['ProductsPerPage'] = $_POST['ProductsPerPage'];
         $submittedvalue = $_SESSION['ProductsPerPage'];

        }

        ?>
        <form action="" name="products" method="post">
        <select project="ProductsPerPage" id="ProductsPerPage" name="ProductsPerPage">
         <option value = "<?php echo $value0; ?>"<?php echo ($value0 == $submittedvalue)?" SELECTED":""?>><?php echo $value0; ?></option>
         <option value = "<?php echo $value1; ?>"<?php echo ($value0 == $submittedvalue)?" SELECTED":""?>><?php echo $value1; ?></option>
         <option value = "<?php echo $value2; ?>"<?php echo ($value0 == $submittedvalue)?" SELECTED":""?>><?php echo $value2; ?></option>
         <option value = "<?php echo $value3; ?>"<?php echo ($value0 == $submittedvalue)?" SELECTED":""?>><?php echo $value3; ?></option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

        </form>


      <?php
      global $submittedvalue;
      $cols = $submittedValue;
      return $cols;

      }


function mywoocommerce_products_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
         session_start();
         global $submittedvalue;
         //$submittedvalue = '5';
         $_SESSION['ProductsPerPage'] = $_POST['ProductsPerPage'];
         $submittedvalue = $_SESSION['ProductsPerPage'];
         $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $submittedvalue );

    }
}

add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'custom_disable_redirect_canonical' );
function custom_disable_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url ) {
    if ( is_paged() && is_singular() ) $redirect_url = false; 
    return $redirect_url; 
}
```

If someone could help getting the pagination to work as well, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Peter I've rewritten the answer which I hope helps - but sorry the pagination wasn't fully working in the new code

Answer (score 0):

Try change your `jc_get_products_per_page()` function with something like this.

```
    function() jc_get_products_max($ppp=5) {
        if(!empty($ppp)) {
            $ppp = (int)$ppp;
            if($ppp != 0 && $ppp >= -1){
                return $ppp;
            }
        }           
    }
    function jc_get_products_per_page(){    
        global $woocommerce; 
        $count = jc_get_products_max();  
        $options = jc_get_products_per_page_options();
        if(isset($_POST['jc-woocommerce-products-per-page'])){ 
                $count = jc_get_products_max($_POST['jc-woocommerce-products-per-page']);
        } else {
            if(isset($woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page)){
                    $count = jc_get_products_max($woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page);
            }
        }
        $woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page = $count;
        return $count;
    }
```